# Regex delete certain lines

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a csv file which has some lines containing `:`. I need completely remove those lines. This is what I've done so far.

```
var array = fs.readFileSync('../list/fusion.csv').toString();
var pattern = /^\:/gm;
var best = array.replace(pattern, '');

fs.writeFile('../list/full.csv', best, function (err) {
 if (err) return console.log(err);
});
```

I try to replace `:` with space. My pattern works in regex101, but when i run code nothing happens.

Comment: What exactly happens?  You say "nothing happens".  How did you execute the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way also to remove the line that has `:`. I've added a demo depicting how to remove the whole line that contains that unnecessary character `:` in your `.csv` file

```js
const regex = /^.*(:).*$/gm;
const str = `id,name,age
1,aaboss,11
2,eeboss,18
3,:ddboss,15
4,ccboss,14
:5,aboss,13
6,boss,12
7,boss,100:
8,boss,12
`;
const subst = ``;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
// using replace again to remove the empty lines
const result = str.replace(regex, subst).replace(/(^[ \t]*\n)/gm, "");
console.log(result);
```

**REGEX:** https://regex101.com/r/JHeRyl/1

Comment: @I'-'I :) my bad. **Edited** for JS version :) :P. Thanks :)

Comment: I dont want those empty lines in my document. Ihave some data before and after those empty lines is what i need to delete.

Comment: @Vil4nte I've edited that mate, See again. :) Hope this will work for your now. :) Let me know is it ok or not ?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to remove lines containing `:` you should specify the `m` flag to allow `^` to match the beginning of every line rather than just the beginning of the string. Your pattern should also be made to match the entire line rather than just `:`.

Change:

```
var pattern = /^\:/g;
```

to:

```
var pattern = /^.*?:.*?$/gm;
```

Comment: Well thanks to you now it recognizes '':'' and i been able to replace it whit a space. But how do i completely remove those lines? Which contains some spaces now.

Comment: I've updated my answer to allow removal of the entire lines.